# Symfony Easyadmin ManyToMany Fields On Index Page

Tags: php, symfony, easyadmin, symfony2-easyadmin

I have three entities:

- Attendee (holds basic attendee information)
- Project (holds basic project information)
- Attendance (links attendees and projects and holds more information like "invited_at", "is_confirmed"...)

One attendee can attend one project only once, but can of course attend multiple projects.

When I filter by project on the attendance index page one attendee can have only one or no attendance. In this case I want to display the corresponding attendance's information (like `invited_at`).

But fields like `attendances.invited_at` show no informartion on the attendee index page.

I guess this due to the n:n relation. Because fields like attendee.firstname are displayed without a problem on the attendances index page.

How can I get the attandance extra information to display on the attendee's index page?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, there is a quite obvious solution for this problem. Custom fields.

https://symfony.com/bundles/EasyAdminBundle/current/fields.html